# Apple's weather app fetches as soon as an Internet connection is made after being disconnected. Is there a better way to do this besides a while loop?

Tags: ios, networking, swift

Psuedocode of my current solution:

```
if (disconnected):
    while (disconnected):
        check for connection
    if (connected):
        fetch results
```

Is there a more idiomatic way to tell when the device goes from being disconnected to establishing an internet connection?

Comment: Ios is not my thing, but I'd be looking for an event that's fired when a connection is made and hooking into that.

Comment: You can use SCNetworkReachability - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/SCNetworkReachabilityRef/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Apple's [Reachability sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)

You don't have to investigate detailed implementation of [Reachability.m](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Reachability_Reachability_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Reachability_Reachability_m-DontLinkElementID_8). You can just use it as a library.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely! This is what [SCNetworkReachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/WhyNetworkingIsHard/WhyNetworkingIsHard.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH13-SW3) is for!
Unfortunately, people tend to use it incorrectly. What you are describing would be a correct use case for it.

- Attempt a connection normally.
- If it fails with `NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet`:

  - Use `SCNetworkReachability` to monitor the device network configuration for changes
  - When the network configuration moves to a state that indicates packets can again leave the device, your application will be notified and you can make connections again.

What you should NOT do is try to use SCNetworkReachability to see if the device is connected before connecting. This is not recommended for many reasons. The SCNetworkReachability API can tell you when it is, or is not, possible for packets to leave the device. It can't tell you if the thing you're connecting to is down, DNS isn't working, etc.

The Apple sample projects [MVCNetworking](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MVCNetworking/Introduction/Intro.html) and [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) demonstrate use of the `SCNetworkReachability` API.

In practice, this looks like....

In your connection error handling:

```
if ([[error domain] isEqualToString:NSURLErrorDomain]){
    NSURL   *failingURL = [[error userInfo] valueForKey:NSURLErrorFailingURLErrorKey];
    switch ([error code]){
        case NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet:
            [self beginObservingReachabilityStatusForHost:[failingURL host]];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

The `beginObservingReachabilityStatusForHost:` and `endObsvervingReachabilityStatusForHost:` methods:

```
- (void) beginObservingReachabilityStatusForHost:(NSString *)host {
    SCNetworkReachabilityRef        reachabilityRef     = NULL;

    void (^callbackBlock)(SCNetworkReachabilityFlags) = ^(SCNetworkReachabilityFlags flags) {
        BOOL reachable = (flags & kSCNetworkReachabilityFlagsReachable) != 0;
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            [self host:host didBecomeReachable:reachable];
        }];
    };

    SCNetworkReachabilityContext context = {
        .version = 0,
        .info = (void *)CFBridgingRetain(callbackBlock),
        .release = CFRelease
    };


    if ([host length] > 0){
        reachabilityRef = SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName(kCFAllocatorDefault, [host UTF8String]);
        if (SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback(reachabilityRef, ReachabilityCallback, &context)){
            if (!SCNetworkReachabilitySetDispatchQueue(reachabilityRef, [self scNetworkQueue]) ){
                // Remove our callback if we can't use the queue
                SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback(reachabilityRef, NULL, NULL);
            }
            [self setCurrentReachability:reachabilityRef];
        }
    }
}

- (void) endObsvervingReachabilityStatusForHost:(NSString *)host {
    // Un-set the dispatch queue
    if (!SCNetworkReachabilitySetDispatchQueue([self currentReachability], NULL) ){

    }
    SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback([self currentReachability], NULL, NULL);
}
```

The C callback that wraps our block:

```
static void ReachabilityCallback(SCNetworkReachabilityRef target, SCNetworkConnectionFlags flags, void* info) {
    void (^callbackBlock)(SCNetworkReachabilityFlags) = (__bridge id)info;
    callbackBlock(flags);
}
```

And the method that the block calls to do something when reachability changes:

```
- (void) host:(NSString *)host didBecomeReachable:(BOOL)reachable {
    // Update your UI to indicate reachability status here
    if (reachable){
        [self endObsvervingReachabilityStatusForHost:nil];
    }
}
```

Obviously to use the above you need a serial dispatch queue and a way to hold on to the SCNetworkReachabilityRef for later cancellation when you're done.